# Showing Data from multiple database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a Index page, which will be more of a "Dashboard" type of page. In this Dashboard page, I would like to populate data from multiple tables. Let's say user XYZ, is logged in. Once he is logged in, I would like to display data from Articles Table, News Table, and Requests table.

This is what I have so far:

```
private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var articles = db.articles.Take(3);
    // var news = db.news.Take(3); - How to display this and requests?
    // var requests = db.requests.Take(3); 
    return View(articles.ToList());
}

@model IEnumerable<GB.Models.articles>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Daskboard</h2>

// Article Info Here

// I would like News/Requests info here
```

Thanks everyone for your help!
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The super-easy way would be a view model wrapping the domain models:

```
public class DashboardIndexViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<News> News { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

Populate this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var vm = new DashboardIndexViewModel {
        Articles = db.articles.Take(3),
        News = db.news.Take(3),
        Requests = db.requests.Take(3)
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

In the view you can access each list of items:

```
@model DashboardIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Daskboard</h2>
@foreach (var a in Model.Articles) {
    <p>....</p>
}

@foreach (var n in Model.News) {
    <p>....</p>
}


@foreach (var r in Model.Requests) {
    <p>....</p>
}
```

Comment: This has worked flawlessly. Over 9000 thanks to you.